# Strange Error :- System.Web.HttpCompileException was unhandled by user code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I habe a partial view named _GetRequestors, that have an IPagedList, it use to work well . but currently when i am trying to view this view i am getting the following error :-

> System.Web.HttpCompileException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147467259   Message=c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\TMS\TMS\Views\Customer_GetRequestors.cshtml(95):
>   error CS1061: 'PagedList.IPagedList' does not
>   contain a definition for 'ORG_ID' and no extension method 'ORG_ID'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'PagedList.IPagedList' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Source=System.Web   ErrorCode=-2147467259   WebEventCode=0
>   SourceCode=#pragma checksum "C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual
>   studio 2012\Projects\TMS\TMS\Views\customer_GetRequestors.cshtml"
>   "{ff1816ec-aa5e-4d10-87f7-6f4963833460}"
>   "9F77A32094FED764FF25BFFEBB39D9D953E8EBF5"
>   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------ //  //     This code was generated by a tool. //
>   Runtime Version:4.0.30319.19080 // //     Changes to this file may
>   cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if //     the code is
>   regenerated. // 
>   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> namespace ASP {
>       using System;
>       using System.Collections.Generic;
>       using System.IO;
>       using System.Linq;
>       using System.Net;
>       using System.Web;
>       using System.Web.Helpers;
>       using System.Web.Security;
>       using System.Web.UI;
>       using System.Web.WebPages;
>       using System.Web.Mvc;
>       using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
>       using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
>       using System.Web.Optimization;
>       using System.Web.Routing;
>       using PagedList;
>       using PagedList.Mvc;
>       using TMS.Models;
>
> ```
> public class _Page_Views_customer__GetRequestors_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IPagedList<TMS.Models.AaaUser>> {
> ```
>
> ## line hidden
>
> ```
>     public _Page_Views_customer__GetRequestors_cshtml() {
>     }
>
>     protected ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance {
>         get {
>             return ((ASP.global_asax)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I see, the view `GetRequestors.cshtml` attempted to call a method or variable named `ORG_ID` in generic list that implements `IPagedList` of `TSM.Models.AaaUser` but type object does not have a method called `ORG_ID` and if have, this is not visible or is protected

make sure that `ORG_ID` can be access